# How to build a Fluent Nested Guard API

Tags: c#, lambda, fluent

I am building a simple Guard API to protect against illegal parameters being passed to functions and so on.

I have the following code:

```
public static class Guard
{
    public static GuardArgument<T> Ensure<T>(T value, string argumentName)
    {
        return new GuardArgument<T>(value, argumentName);
    }
}

public class GuardArgument<T>
{
    public GuardArgument(T value, string argumentName)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = Name;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

// Example extension for validity checks
public static GuardArgument<T> IsNotNull<T>(this GuardArgument<T> guardArgument, string errorMessage)
{
    if (guardArgument.Value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(guardArgument.Name, errorMessage);
    }

    return guardArgument;
}
```

At the moment the code can be used in a similar way to (note this is just a dumb example):

```
void DummyMethod(int? someObject) {

    Guard.Ensure(someObject, "someObject")
       .IsNotNull()
       .IsGreaterThan(0)
       .IsLessThan(10);
}
```

This all works fine.  What I want to be able to do now is extend the API to include child properties in the checks in the following way:

```
Guard.Ensure(someObject, "someObject")
    .IsNotNull()
    .Property(
        (x => x.ChildProp1, "childProp1")
           .IsNotNull()
           .IsGreaterThan(10)
     )
     .Property(
        (x => x.ChildProp2, "childProp2")
           .IsNotNull()
           .IsLessThan(10)
     );
```

Obviously the new `.Property` method needs to return the parent `GuardArgument` in order to chain. Furthermore the child property needs to be able to use the existing check methods (`IsNotNull()` etc) to avoid code duplication.

I cannot work out how to construct the lambda/Property function parameters or where the `.Property` method should be located - i.e. should it be a property on the `GuardArgument` or somewhere else, or even if there is a better structure to the API.

Comment: Might be a typo, but the GuardArgument constructor sets `Name = Name`

Comment: You say, "Obviously the new `.Property` method needs to return the parent `GuardArgument` in order to chain." - No. That's not correct. If you're trying to make a fluent API then you shouldn't pass the parent - you should construct a new `GuardArgument` that nests the parent otherwise you can create awful bugs by retaining references along the chain and then trying to build new chains from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function allows for a similar syntax to what you want.

```
public static GuardArgument<T> Property<T, TProp>(this GuardArgument<T> guardArgument, Func<T, TProp> getProperty, string propertyName, Action<GuardArgument<TProp>> validate)
{
    GuardArgument<TProp> propertyGuardArgument = new GuardArgument<TProp>(getProperty(guardArgument.Value), propertyName);

    validate(propertyGuardArgument);

    return guardArgument;
}
```

The function creates a new GuardArgument for the selected property and then passes this into the `Action` parameter to allow you to validate as you wish.

This also allows infinite chaining of properties, although I'm not sure that would be particularly readable.

Usage:

```
Guard.Ensure(someObject, "someObject")
     .IsNotNull()
     .Property(x => x.ChildProp1, "childProp1", childProp1 =>
         childProp1.IsNotNull()
                   .IsLessThan(10)
                   .Property(y => y.InnerChildProperty, "innerChildProperty", innerChildProperty =>
                       innerChildProperty.IsNotNull()
                    )
     )
     .Property(x => x.ChildProp2, "childProp2", childProp2 =>
         childProp2.IsNotNull()
                   .IsGreaterThan(10)
     );
```

Comment: Looks like JavaScript "pyramid of doom" ;)

Comment: Anyway, remember that you can flatten it declaring and creating Func and Action first outside the fluent and then pass them to Property().

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no benefit from putting the property checks in the chain of the parent object checks. So I would recommend to make one chain for the parent object and for each property another chain. This is much more readable:

```
  Guard.Ensure(a, "a")
    .IsNotNull("a is null");
  Guard.Ensure(a.p0, "a.p0")
    .IsGreaterThan(10);
  Guard.Ensure(a.p1, "a.p1")
    .IsGreaterThan(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reinventing a wheel here. Install this extension - [Code Contracts](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) and here is [docs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) how to use it.

In addition to code based asserts similar to yours, i.e. :

```
 public int[] Bar(){
   Contract.Ensures( Contract.ForAll(0, Contract.Result<int[]>().Length, index => Contract.Result<int[]>()[index] > 0));

 ....
 }
```

or

```
 Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>( x.Value.NestedObject != null, ”x.Value.NestedObject” );
```

But also has attributes and extensive set of functions for checking interfaces, nice pre- and post- conditions etc. check it out!

Comment: I've used Code Contracts on a project and found them a pain to use. They reduce the build speed to a crawl. After a couple of months we took them out and went for something like the question instead.

Comment: Thank you @Sean, we recently started using them, and do not have a lot, so have not noticed build time to be much worse yet.

Comment: I've already looked at Code Contracts and like Sean, build speed was slow and was only really being used for guarding method input.  Hence the need for something much lighter in weight..